# how do I reference a workspace directory in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2008 and I have a few files that I want to reference when in #debug mode. How do I get the directory of the workspace so that I do not have to manually change it every time I am at a different computer?

For instance, when I'm at work, my workspace is in c:\work2, when I'm at home, it is in d:\work.

This isn't an issue on the live product but it is when I change computers or other uses load the project since the files are in different directories for each workspace.

thanks!
Eroc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the test files (XML, spreadsheet, etc) as a 'Resource.' [How to Add a Resource to your Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Then, in your test files, you can use a relative address to access those files.

```
private const String = "./testFile1.xml";
```

Comment: I started with this and I was hoping to have a little more freedom but this was the route I went. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to have some [pre-build](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx) command to change directory.